Upload multiple images and show WPF
My problem may not be loading the images, but rather the timing.
The images are only shown at the end of the process, and not as soon as I change the origin of the image.
The logic of the process is, I call external graphics, they return the image of themselves, and I place them in grids to display as icons.
However, I want it to be displayed as soon as the first one returns, and not just when all the images are finished.
This is a project prototype, it needs to be optimized with lists, but this dynamic update is important
Part of the XAML code:
///I have several grids like this, for each image
<Grid>
   <Image Width="600" Height="363" Name="GraFrota_img"
          MouseLeftButtonDown="GraFrota_click" Visibility="Hidden" Stretch="Fill"/>
      <TextBlock Name="txtGraFrota" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Visibility="Visible">
         Carregando Imagem do Gráfico
      </TextBlock>
</Grid>

Code behind
public BrowseAcidentes()
{
            
   InitializeComponent();
   ContentRendered += (sender, e) =>
   {

      CarregaGrafico();
    };
}

private void CarregaGrafico()
{
   capturaTela("FR", grafrota.abre(2, true));
   ///I call several graphs here
   ....
}

private void capturaTela(string pGrafico,Bitmap pBmp = null)
{
            
 if (pBmp != null)
 {
     MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
     pBmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);

     BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
     bitmap.BeginInit();
     bitmap.StreamSource = memory;
     bitmap.EndInit();

     switch (pGrafico)
     {
       case "FR":                      
                
         GraFrota_img.Source = bitmap;
         GraFrota_img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         txtGraFrota.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
         break;

      ///I call several graphs here
     }
}


bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation; ... Causes a BitmapSource object to delay initialization until it is necessary. This is useful when dealing with collections of images.
